# Issue with p:ajax event colReorder

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Inside a `p:dataTable` i have some ajax events that display FacesMessages when i edit something

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{userRegistrationController.cellEditAction}"
                            update=":currentUserForm:currentUsersFormMessages"/>
<p:ajax event="colResize" listener="#{userRegistrationController.colResizeAction}"
                            update=":currentUserForm:currentUsersFormMessages"/>
<p:ajax event="colReorder"  listener="#{userRegistrationController.colReorderAction}"
                            update=":currentUserForm:currentUsersFormMessages"/>
```

The only one that's not working is the "colReorder" one, when i call the method i have **javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.mycompany.primeautosales.jsf.UserRegistrationController@476d042d.colReorderAction(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)** . 
Here are the methods `colResizeAction` and `colReorderAction`, i don't get why one work and the other doesn't.

```
public void colResizeAction(ColumnResizeEvent event){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
            "the width of column "+event.getColumn()+" is now "+event.getWidth()
    ));
}

public void colReorderAction(ReorderEvent event){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
            "reordered "+event.getComponent().toString()));
}
```

Is there something wrong with `ReorderEvent` class ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the bean Action parameter ty change to action behavior like below code

```
public void onReorder(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
 DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) event.getComponent();
 List<UIColumn> columns = dataTable.getColumns();

 //build new column order to store  
 for(UIColumn : column columns)
 {
  //read column names
 }
//store list to db
}
```

for reference [Click here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=29571)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ajax event "colReorder" does not support the listener parameter org.primefaces.event.ReorderEvent. That's why you have this error! As the @Araf mentioned above, the AjaxBehaviorEvent event is supported by the colReorder event.